# How to print to file using ostream_iterator?

Tags: c++, random

I have the following code (mooched from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)) to randomize a vector of 1500 values, and I want to place them in a textfile but can't. Honestly, I don't fully understand how this code works, so I'd like someone to explain to me how it works and/or how to change the output to a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i; i<1500; ++i){
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::ostream_iteartor<T>` is an iterator returning an object from `operator*()` which writes to a stream upon assignment, followed by the string separator. `std::copy()` assigns each element of the source sequence to an object in the destination sequence, i.e., each object is written to the stream. Just replace `std::cout` with an object of `std::ofstream` opened to write to the target file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `std::cout` and the type `std::ofstream` are both derived from `std::ostream`, which is the same type that `std::ostream_iterator` operates on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

void emit_values(std::ostream& os)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i<1500; ++i){
        v.push_back(i);
    }

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
    os << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    // use stdout
    emit_values(std::cout);

    // use a file
    std::ofstream fs("values.txt");
    emit_values(fs);
    fs.close();    

    return 0;
}
```